# Dividing values with SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to determine the average between 2 values (val1, val2) and they are both columns in my table. Every time I run the code it shows them as 0. I know I'm using code that isn't parametrized but if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong, it would help a lot. This isn't professional code it's just a quick project I've been working on.

```
private static int findAVG(MySqlConnection conn)
{
    int val1;
    int val2;
    float avg;

    string sql = "select val1 from accounts where name = '" + Login.name + "';";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    val1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    sql = "select val2 from accounts where name = '" + Login.name + "';";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    val2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    if (val2 != 0)
    {
        avg = val1 / val2;
    }
    else
    {
        avg = 0;
    }

    sql = "update accounts set avg = " + avg + " where name = '" + Login.name + "';";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: You have *integer division*, please, note that for *integer* we have `1 / 2 == 0` when for *double* `1.0 / 2 == 0.5`. Try `val1 = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you I am going to try that.

Comment: Average should be `(val1 + val2) / 2`.  But, additionally, you're playing with integers so the result will be an integer.  Try:  `avg = (decimal)(val1 + val2) / (decimal)2` or `avg = (decimal)(val1 + val2) / 2m;`

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause is *integer division*: when you *divide* two integers, `val1 / val2` in your case, the result
will be *integer*  as well, e.g. `1 / 2 == 0`.

So quick correction will be converting to `double` instead of `int`:

```
double val1;
double val2;
doubel avg;

...

val1 = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

...

val2 = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

...
```

A better choice is to let *RDMBS* do the work (table `update`) for you:

```
private static int findAVG(MySqlConnection conn) {
  //DONE: do not hardcode, but parametrize the query (@prm_Name) 
  string sql = 
    @"update Accounts
         set avg = val1 / val2
       where name = @prm_Name"; 

  //DONE: wrap IDisposable (cmd) in using 
  using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_Name", Login.name);

    // let's return number of records affected 
    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
  }
}
```